# Making SVG file interactive in D3.js

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, svg

I have created a layout algorithm for graph visualization so that y position of each node corresponds to time and the graph starts from the top (t=0) and grows dawnwards. I also draw edges with bazier forms I made. Also the color of the edges vary throughout the edge. I need the layout/look to remain the same. Currently, I am using pycairo for drawing the graph that generates a CSV file (potentially, I can create other formats such as PDF,PNG too). My goal is to make the visualization interactive, for example to be able to click on specific nodes and get the data related to that node back. I couldn't figure out how to do this in python. Now, I want to do this in JavaScript and D3.js.
My question is how can I make the CSV output interactive? For example, when clicking on a node, it should return its y position (which represents time), and some other attributes. I also want to be able to jump to a certain y position in a graph given user's input. 
It would also be helpful to give me some clues on how to think about this problem.

[image]

This is a screenshot of what the final result looks like. The horizontal lines are really not important

Comment: D3.js is very powerful, and should be able to do what you want. I would recommend building your visualisation up from scratch in D3, rather than trying to somehow modify your pycairo output. There are plenty of tutorials on D3 to get you started. Many examples here as well - https://d3js.org/

Comment: So there is no way to start with the SVG and make that responsive?

Comment: Feel free to post an image, some code, a sketch or something.

Comment: I have added an image of what those renderings look like!